# Does (n > 0 || -1) evaluate to true/false? If so, how can it then be multiplied?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the implementation of `indexOf` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). This is what I'm curious about:

```
n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
```

It seems to me that `(n > 0 || -1)` is going to evaluate to `true` or `false`, but then it's being multiplied?

In case the link ever breaks, this is the `indexOf` implementation from MDN:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read more about the JavaScript `||` operator. It is not the same as C. Also, read about type conversions. They are also not the same as C.

Comment: Also, you need to fix your title. It is unlikely to be useful to future visitors with the same question.

Comment: @RaymondChen What would you recommend?

Comment: How about "Why is (n>0 || -1) used in multiplication in the implementation of indexOf?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript logical operators and results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283366/javascript-logical-operators-and-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to me that (n > 0 || -1) is going to evaluate to true or false

Nope. The `||` operator in JavaScript is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), if `n` is `<= 0`, that expression results in `-1`, not `false`.

If `n > 0`, that expression will indeed yield `true`, and yes, they really are multiplying `true` by a number. That's okay (**I** wouldn't do it, but it's allowed), `true` will get automatically coerced into a number (`1`), because both sides of a `*` are coerced to numbers before the multiplication. The conversion of various types to numbers is in [Section 9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) of the spec.

Answer (score 2):

first:

```
(n > 0 || -1)
```

Which goes in the following order:

```
  n > 0  // if true it stops here and -1 is not evaluated.
  -1
```

Then it tries to multiply either

```
   true * Math.floor(Math.abs(n))
   or
   -1 * Math.floor(Math.abs(n))
```

And finally it either stores:

```
n = 1 * Math.floor(Math.abs(n))
or 
n = -1 * Math.floor(Math.abs(n))
```

Comment: The `true` is converted to 1

Comment: What's the point of doing effectively `sgn(x) * floor(abs(x))` when `~~x` seems to do the same?

Comment: In my opinion ~~ is ok, but read this if you want to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @JanDvorak `~~` will blow up if `x` can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: @NullUserException so shall `Math.abs(x)`, shan't it?

Comment: Or, the purpose is to not get `NaN` converted to `0`?

Comment: @JanDvorak `Math.abs()` and `Math.floor()` will operate on JavaScript `Number`s without conversion. So they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part is false then it would multiply by `-1`, otherwise it would multiply by `1`. The `OR` operator returns the right hand side of the expression if the left hand side is **"falsy"**