# Logical AND assignment

Tags: javascript

I want to do a logical AND between `var a` and `var b` and assign the result to `var a`

I know how to do this with the bitwise AND : `a &= b`
But instead of having `1` or `0` as result, i want `true` or `false` (i.e logical instead of bitwise). Can I do this in javascript ?

```js
var boolArr1 = [true, true, true];
var boolArr2 = [true, true, false];

var res1 = true;
var res2 = true;

boolArr1.forEach(i => res1 &= i);
boolArr2.forEach(i => res2 &= i);

document.write("res1 = "+res1); //should write true instead of 1
document.write("<br>");
document.write("res2 = "+res2); //should write false instead of 0
```

**NB.** I know I could do  `a = a && b`

Comment: Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283366/javascript-logical-operators-and-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent single (combined) operator that does `a = a && b`.

You can modify your code slightly to achieve what you want which doesn't quite use this construct, but in reality it just hides it behind function calls and results:

```js
var boolArr1 = [true, true, true, null, true];
var boolArr2 = [true, true, false];

var res1 = boolArr1.reduce((prev, cur) => prev && cur, true);
var res2 = boolArr2.reduce((prev, cur) => prev && cur, true);

document.write("res1 = "+res1); // writes true
document.write("<br>");
document.write("res2 = "+res2); // writes false
```

Another point to remember is that no type conversion is being done. The `&&` operator evaluates to one of the values on either side of the operator, the first of it can be converted to `false` or the second if not.

Comment: `var res1 = boolArr1.every(i => i);` is more readable in this case.

Comment: @vp_arth - I don't see what that has to do with the question. The question is about `&&`, which my answer tries to address. If the intention is to test of all values are truthy, then you're correct, but the question should be modified.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var boolArr1 = [true, true, true];
var boolArr2 = [true, true, false];

var res1 = true;
var res2 = true;

boolArr1.forEach(i => res1 &= i);
boolArr2.forEach(i => res2 &= i);

document.write("res1 = "+ Boolean(res1)); //should write true instead of 1
document.write("<br>");
document.write("res2 = "+ Boolean(res2)); //should write false instead of 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of `&=` is an integer, which is bit-per-bit binary `and` operation.

You can't to use `&=` operation for booleans at all.

Inspect this:

```
var a = 1; //  001b
var b = 2; //  010b
a &= b;    //  001b & 010b = 0
console.log(a); // 0
```

You must always use `a = a && b;` if you mean booleans.

---

As `is all elements of array is truthy` I suggest followed one-liner:

```
arr.every(b => b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in combination with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

```js
var boolArr1 = [true, true, true],
    boolArr2 = [true, true, false];

document.write('boolArr1: ' + boolArr1.every(Boolean));
document.write('<br>');
document.write('boolArr2: ' + boolArr2.every(Boolean));
```